# Маленький скрипт на bash

Tags: bash

Скрипт при запуске должен выбрать 1 любой файл с нужным расширением в /home/papka1/ и переместить его в /home/papka2/
В случае, если файлов нет, то вывести сообщение об этом.

Папка с файлами - /home/papka1/ 
Куда перемещать - /home/papka2/ 
файлы с именами - %random%.jjjj

Comment: @qwerty777, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mv "`ls /home/papka1/*.jjjj | head -1`" /home/papka2/
```

Comment: Перенаправлять вывод ls на конвейер - так себе идея. Это сломается, если в имени файла будет `\n`. Для неинтерактивного перечисления файлов надо всегда использовать `find -print0`.